# Почему private поле другого объекта доступно внутри самого класса?

Tags: java, ооп, доступ

Есть следующий кусок кода:

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean equalsPerson(Person p){
        System.out.println(this.name);
        System.out.println(p.name);
        return p.name.equals(this.name);
    }
}
```

Почему p.name Доступна?
Ведь name объявлена как private, а значит у объекта p, она не должна быть доступна.
 Но она доступна. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поведение `private` и других модификаторов доступа описано в спецификации Java [§6.6.1 «Определение доступности»](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> ... Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level type ([§7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.
>
> ... *В противном случае, если член или конструктор объявлен как `private`, доступ разрешен тогда и только тогда, когда он осуществляется из тела класса верхнего уровня ([§7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)), который охватывает объявление члена класса или конструктора.*

В данном случае класс верхнего уровня: `Person`. То, что `name` объявлен как `private` говорит о том, что к нему можно обращаться в любом месте внутри класса `Person`. При этом неважно относится `name` к текущему объекту (`this`) или к другому объекту `Person`.

Answer (score 3):

Модификатор доступа `private` защищает члены класса от доступа из кода, находящегося в *других классах*, а не в *других объектах*.

Comment: хорошо, а почему тогда
`public class MainMain {
 MainMain(){
  
 }
 MainMain(Person person){
  System.out.println(person.name);
 }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  Person person = new Person();
   MainMain main = new MainMain(person);
 }
}`
говорит, что private и нельзя?

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Не понял.

Comment: как понять "защищает члены класса от доступа из кода, находящегося в других классах, а не в других объектах"?
Ведь если в любом другом классе пытаешься обратиться, то ошибка. А именно в классе объекта, то нет ошибки.

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Это тот же самый класс, что и тот класс к полю которого Вы обращаетесь.  Поэтому можно.

Comment: Т.е из класса я могу обращать к private полям его объектов?

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Обращайтесь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104952/discussion-between---and-igor).